# How to implement sequential back-end calls in WSO2 EI/ESB?

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I want to implement sequential back-end calls in WSO2 Integration Studio.

After the first back-end call, I want to send a few fields from the response from the first back-end call to the second back-end call.

I tried using payload factory mediator inside a for-each loop after the http back-end call, but it is giving only last object.

Any other way to get it done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need a foreach loop here. You can implement a Service Chain pattern. You can create a Payload using the PayloadFactory mediator to use in second call which uses the values from the first call's response. Have a look at the following sample.

```
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="ServiceChaining" context="/servicechain">
   <resource methods="GET">
      <inSequence>
         <call>
            <endpoint>
               <http uri-template="http://www.mocky.io/v2/5eb1cf1d320000749428f99e"/>
            </endpoint>
         </call>
         <payloadFactory media-type="json">
            <format>{"Hello" : {"test1" :  "$1", "test3": "$2"}}</format>
            <args>
               <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.key1"/>
               <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.key3"/>
            </args>
         </payloadFactory>
         <call>
            <endpoint>
               <http method="POST" uri-template="http://www.mocky.io/v2/5185415ba171ea3a00704eed"/>
            </endpoint>
         </call>
         <respond/>
      </inSequence>
   </resource>
</api>
```

Comment: Hey Arunan, thanks for this. But my use-case has little complexion. Can you please check this link for the detailed explanation. Thanks in advance.
             https://stackoverflow.com/q/61653131/13424730