# Sequential back-end calls in WSO2 EI/ESB

Tags: wso2, esb, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

In my case, the response from the first back-end call is in **Array of Objects** format as below:

Response:

```
"Entity": {
        "related-List": [
            {
                "fname": "abc",
                "lname": "xyz",
                "bdate": "2013-01-25",
                "accType": "Cur",
                "accNum": "54736",
                "bal": 901,
                "address": "USA"
            },
            {
                "fname": "def",
                "lname": "pqr",
                "bdate": "2013-01-25",
                "accType": "Sav",
                "accNum": "12345",
                "bal": 901,
                "address": "USA"
            },
            {
                "fname": "ghi",
                "lname": "stu",
                "bdate": "2013-01-25",
                "accType": "Dep",
                "accNum": "87654",
                "bal": 901,
                "address": "USA"
            }
]
}
```

*************/

So in the second call, I want to use the "accType" and "accNum" from the response and make the back-end call for the number of objects present in the response array. For this, I need to use Iterate or ForEach like:

```
<foreach>
<call>
            <endpoint>
               <http method="POST" uri-template="http://localhost:6754/v2/{accType}/{accNum}"/>
            </endpoint>
</call>
</foreach>
```

OR

```
<iterate>
    <call>
                <endpoint>
                   <http method="POST" uri-template="http://localhost:6754/v2/{accType}/{accNum}"/>
                </endpoint>
    </call>
</iterate>
```

**What is the correct way to implement it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use Send or Call mediators inside Foreach mediator. Hence you have to use Iterate mediator. You can use Iterate mediator expression as **json-eval($. Entity.related-List)** and iterate through the array.

Comment: How do I store the **accType** and **accNum** from each object from the array of objects from the response, so that I can pass it to Iterate mediator to do parallel back-end calls?                                                                                                                       
As I have mentioned in the main question, I'm getting response in array of objects format.

Comment: When you iterate through the array of objects, the message body will contain only that particular object. You can use jsonpath to read those values. Have a look at this blog as well. https://medium.com/@arunans23/iterate-over-json-payload-with-wso2-enterprise-integrator-8ccb9cdd2c70